# what will be faster - copy files separetly to s3 or move them inside the bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a a few directories with about 1000 files each. The size of a directory is about 30G each.
I need to upload these directories to s3 bucket, but each file needs to be in a separate directory.
I'm using AWS SDK for uploading.
What would be the most efficient way to do it?

1. Copy directories as they are and move files inside s3 bucket to final destinations?
2. Run separate command for each file?

For 1st I hope aws libraries will better handle parallelism while updating than I can do with 2nd solution.
But 2nd approach saves me time for moving (in fact copying and deleting) objects inside s3.

Regards

Pawel

Comment: There's no such thing as "directory" in s3. And yes, copying objects inside s3 is usually (much) faster when objects are big.

Comment: It certainly makes much more sense to upload into the final position that to upload and then move. Is time a critical part of your requirements, or is it okay to copy each object on its own? How do you know where to put each file -- is it based on the filename? Is this a one-off job, or something you'll be doing on a repeating basis?

Comment: @oakad - i ment directory from the source structure.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - the final destination is actually build based on source file create data. So if file has name file.txt and was created on 31 July 2021, the final destination in s3 should be s3://mybucket/2021/07/31/file.txt. As I understand it will be faster to copy each file separately and upload them to final destination.